# pytest does not work as expected combined with @cache

Tags: python, pytest

*Question updated after the reply from larsks*

I'm having trouble writing a unit test in Pytest for a cached class. I'm trying to patch `slowfunc` in the code below with `mockfunc`. However, the patch only appears to succeed when I'm not using `@cache`.

```
import pytest
from functools import cache
from unittest.mock import patch

@cache
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("calling init")
        
    def slowfunc(self, text):
        print("calling slowfunc:", text)
        return False
        
    def call(self):
        return self.slowfunc("blah")


class B:
    def call(self):
        a = A()
        return a.call()
            
        
class Test_B:
    def mockfunc(self, text):
        print("calling mockfunc:", text)
        return True
    
    @patch.object(A, 'slowfunc', mockfunc)
    def test_B(self):
        b = B()
        result = b.call()
        assert result == True
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    retcode = pytest.main(["-xs", __file__])
```

Running the code with `@cache` commented out gives the expected result:

```
example.py calling init
calling mockfunc: blah
.

=== 1 passed in 0.07s ===
```

With `@cache` enabled it fails:

```
example.py calling init
calling slowfunc: blah
F

=== FAILURES ===
___ Test_B.test_B ___

self = <example.Test_B object at 0x7f305eaaa1f0>

    @patch.object(A, 'slowfunc', mockfunc)
    def test_B(self):
        b = B()
        result = b.call()
>       assert result == True
E       assert False == True

example.py:27: AssertionError
=== short test summary info ===
FAILED example.py::Test_B::test_B - assert False == True
!!!! stopping after 1 failures !!!
=== 1 failed in 0.23s ===
```

`slowfunc` is called in this case, and the test fails. What's going on? Using `A.cache_clear()` at the start of the test does not resolve the situation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't have a complete explanation for you, it looks like you can work around this issue by patching the function after instantiating your `A` object:

```py
class Test_A:
    def mockfunc(self, text):
        print("calling mockfunc:", text)
        return True

    def test_A(self):
        a = A()
        with patch.object(a, "slowfunc", self.mockfunc):
            result = a.call()
        assert result == True
```

Comment: Excellent find! Unfortunately I have oversimplified my example a bit too much, and this solution won't work for me - see the updated question. Do you also have an idea for this?